# Power Query On Hand Inventory

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to calculate rolling on hand inventory in power query at a week level for each location and product type.

In general the formula is:

Starting Inventory (System Data) + Receipts (Forecast) - Shipments (Forecast) + Returns (Forecast) = Ending Inventory (Forecast)

The format of the forecast data after pivoting Shipments, Receipts and Returns is:

Location, Product Type, Week, Shipments, Receipts, Returns

A, B, 1, 54, 69, 8

A, B, 2, 98, 12, 3

A, B, 3, 68, 50, 3

A, C, 1, 9, 58, 9

A, C, 2, 95, 20, 5

A, C, 3, 93, 42, 10

D, B, 1, 27, 87, 7

D, B, 2, 5, 2, 4

D, B, 3, 92, 19, 4

D, C, 1, 96, 17, 5

D, C, 2, 50, 50, 7

D, C, 3, 70, 95, 4

The format of the starting inventory is:

Location, Product Type, Starting Inventory

A, B, 116

A, C, 117

D, B, 108

D, C, 197

The desired result is:

Location, Product Type, Week, Shipments, Receipts, Returns, Ending Inventory

A, B, 1, 54, 69, 8, 139

A, B, 2, 98, 12, 3, 56

A, B, 3, 68, 50, 3, 41

A, C, 1, 9, 58, 9, 175

A, C, 2, 95, 20, 5, 105

A, C, 3, 93, 42, 10, 64

D, B, 1, 27, 87, 7, 175

D, B, 2, 5, 2, 4, 176

D, B, 3, 92, 19, 4, 107

D, C, 1, 96, 17, 5, 123

D, C, 2, 50, 50, 7, 130

D, C, 3, 70, 95, 4, 159

My internet searches make me think it would be done best with List.Generate, but I am not finding clear enough examples for me to follow.

So far I have only exported to excel and done the calculation there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show your data as text; an example of your expected results; and the code you have tried. You may find useful: [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=For%20larger%20code%20snippets%2C%20you,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i made the changes as requested 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.

Read the code comments and explore the Applied steps to better understand the algorithm

```
let
// Change Source= and Source2= lines to reflect the actual table names of the respective tables

//Read in the Inventory table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Inventory"]}[Content],
    Inventory = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Location", type text}, {"Product Type", type text}, {"Starting Inventory", Int64.Type}}),

//Read in the Data table
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    Data = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"Location", type text}, {"Product Type", type text}, {"Week", Int64.Type}, {"Shipments", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Receipts", Int64.Type}, {"Returns", Int64.Type}}),

// "Lookup" Starting inventory for each Location/Product type
//    by doing a Table.Join
    #"Join Starting Inventory" = Table.NestedJoin(Data,{"Location","Product Type"}, Inventory,{"Location","Product Type"},
        "Joined", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

//Extract only the starting inventory column
    #"Expanded Joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Join Starting Inventory", "Joined", {"Starting Inventory"}, {"Starting Inventory"}),

//Group by Location and Product Type
//Then use List.Generate to calculate the Running Ending Inventory for each Location/Product type
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Joined", {"Location", "Product Type"}, {
        {"Calc", (t)=>
            let 
                Ending = List.Generate(
                    ()=>[e=t[Starting Inventory]{0} + t[Receipts]{0} - t[Shipments]{0} + t[Returns]{0}, idx=0],
                    each [idx]< Table.RowCount(t),
                    each [e=[e] + t[Receipts]{[idx]+1} - t[Shipments]{[idx]+1} + t[Returns]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
                    each [e])
            in 

//Add the Ending Inventory List as a new column
//   while removing the Starting Inventory column
                Table.FromColumns(
                    Table.ToColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(t,"Starting Inventory")) & {Ending},
                    Table.ColumnNames(Data) & {"Ending Inventory"})}}),

//Expand the Grouped tables
    #"Expanded Calc" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Calc", 
        List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Data),2) & {"Ending Inventory"}),

//Set data types
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Calc",
                List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Calc"),2), each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    typeIt
```

[image]